# Why passport returns "Unauthenticated" when trying to get access token via "api/login" through postman?

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-passport

So, I have been banging my head for an hour on this problem now. It was working in my old PC, but after pulling it from git, it stopped working.

Below is my api.php:

```
Route::post('/login', 'API\UserController@login');

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function(){
// Some other routes are here
});
```

I am trying to send a post request from postman to get the access token. The request looks something like this:

```
POST /api/login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---- 
WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Accept: application/json
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: aa1a5889-5383-60f4-7425-4c8019f7f144

------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="email"

admin@somewhere.com
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="password"

123456
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

And in response, I get:

```
{
    "message": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

What I've tried so far:

1. Made sure, I followed the passport installation procedure correctly in Laravel 5.6
2. Tried making a .htaccess file in root directory like this:

   RewriteEngine On

   ```
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
   RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
   ```

I am running the server using "php artisan serve" and do not know how to restart the server except for stopping and running it again.

3. Added a line to print the error log in passport with

   error_log($e->getHint());

Which is not printing anything in the laravel log (I am not quite sure where else it might dump its log file).

I have not touched laravel for quite a while and the questions should sound really silly. Help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Can you add your controller code also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was neither in the controller nor with passport. I ended up listing all routes with php artisan and went through all the middleware definition listed with the route "api/login". In my particular case, the "api/login" route was under "api" middleware. Strangely, the api middleware definition had "auth:api" listed underneath. Removed it and everything started to work again. As for the other routes in the api.php, I already had them group under the "auth:api" middleware.

Comment: got a same issue but in my case i put `auth:api`. is there any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
POST /api/login HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8000
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
cache-control: no-cache
Postman-Token: aa1a5889-5383-60f4-7425-4c8019f7f144
{
   "email": "admin@somewhere.com",
   "password": "123456"
}------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--
```

Comment: If they were not correct, it should at least reach my controller code. Why the URL would not be authenticated?

Comment: @Soulslayer Can you edit your question with your controller code?